# Using a function for chaining promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have two functions, one for fetching content and one for saving it..  The contents are different and I need to perform different tasks.  I know what type of content is beforehand, and these two are just helpers functions.

I was using asyncfuncA().then(asyncFuncB).then(...);   but I thought I can use a function that chains A and B and use it like asyncfuncAB.then(...) but I am having problem. The  below simplified code explains what I wanna do.

```
     function getCont(url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve ,reject) {
      // The real code makes request and resolves to response body or rejects with error
     resolve("response body");
        });
     }

     function saveFile  (path,data) {
       return new Promise(function (resolve ,reject) {
     // The real code writes file and resolves to true for success or rejects for error
     resolve(true);
        });
      }

     saveCont("some://url","/some/path").then ( function() {
      // Do some thing for one type of content 
     });

     saveCont("another://url","/another/path").then ( function() {
     // Do another thing for another type of content
     });


    function saveCont(url,path) {
         getCont(url)
         .then(function(content) {
         saveFile(path,data) })
        .then( function() {
         // **  What to put here ??

         });
     };
```

Comment: can't you put whatever you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have to put anything in the end, you just have to return the `Promise` object:

```
function saveCont(url,path) {
     return getCont(url)     //CHANGED
     .then(function(content) {
        return saveFile(path,data);   // if you do not put a return here, saveFile would still work, but the next step in chain would not wait till SaveFile finishes processing. 
     });
 };
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon in CHANGED. Otherwise the next line would be `undefined.then()`

Comment: I'm slowly starting to understand promises.. Thanks and I have accept this answer :)